# Why is 3D-Viewport running very slow?

Tags: 3d-view, frame-rate

I have a scene that i just started animating in and I went to see how it looked and the view port is only running at 10 fps. I would like it to run at 30 fps if possible. Yes, I have a pretty good computer and i don't know why it would be running this slow. Also my scene is NOT very complex so i don't know why it would be doing this, it never has before. Any help or answers are greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Link to scene: http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=48661

The scene has 101K Vertices, 80K Faces and 160K Tris.

Comment: "*i don't know why it would be running this slow*" we don't either unless you provide some actual info about your scene, setup, computer specs, OS, drivers, etc. But I guess you already have your answer at "*Also my scene is very complex*"

Comment: Blender will run at the speed that it can, given the complexity of your scene and the computing power available. You want it to run faster? Simplify, or optimize your scene so that you can keep up the desired frame rate or get a  cluster of supercomputers...

Comment: @cegaton I meant not very complex. It is not very complex.

Comment: @cegaton ok i edited it

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I edited it... please look when you can! thanks :)

Comment: @LoganEbert you still have not posted any information about your scene.  What you consider "not very complex" could mean many things. You've posted in this site before, you should know not wait to be asked for more information and then give it in small doses... the more information you share and the clearer the question, the better chances of getting an answer.

Comment: You still need to tell us what specs of the pc for us to know if this is reasonable. This is entirely reasonable to be 10fps if you have a PC from 2010.

Comment: please use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/to share .blend files (free and permanent) then edit your question and paste the provided link.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comment, I believe that the complex scene keeps the fps low.

If it is difficult to make it simple, use the OpenGL render (the movie mark at the bottom of the 3D view)
It is a way to render animations rapidly.